# Get current network usage with Python

Tags: python, networking, download, monitoring

I'm writing a python script which consists of checking the current network usage of the computer, when downloading something. I've done a lot of research, and most of the things I find online are getting the MAX speed of the PC's NIC. In this case I want the current speed (like in mbps or something) only. The most promising solution I have come across yet is with the library "psutils". So the piece of code goes like this:

```
import psutil

download = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)["Ethernet"][1]
print(download)
```

The output I get is '1392877555' which means it is definitely giving me something, but no matter what I have tried to alter this number, it is ALWAYS very close to this number. Only the last 3 digits vary. If I download something at my max speed my ISP allows me to, I get this number. If I reduce network usage to a minimum (I can monitor it in task manager for testing), I still get this number.

Any ideas why this is happening, or do I need to do something else with this data?

Comment: Try using "Wi-Fi" instead of "Ethernet".

Comment: @thirdsandfourths I'm on desktop with only ethernet. Wifi results in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get current network speed you can use **speedtest-cli** library. Using this library can give you the detailed info on your network speed and it's configurations. For more details you can refer to this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/test-internet-speed-using-python/).

Comment: This is precisely what I do NOT want. I do NOT want the MAX capacity of my downloads, I want the speed at which my NIC is working RIGHT NOW. If I am not downloading anything, I want a result close to 0. Speedtest-cli is just a regular speedtest.